# How to activate user search in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to activate the user search in my wordpress site. Which means that I want also the users on the search result. I have tried some plugins, but none of these gives the solution I want. Is there some code snippet that I can put on `functions.php` that helps to solve my problem? Do I have to use `WP_User_Query`? Thanks!

So far I have used these plugins:

- Relevanssi
- Search everything

Comment: I have used [this](http://wpadvancedsearch.com/) before to create a very customized WordPress search.  You will need some PHP knowledge for this though.  Hope it helps!

Comment: Have you an example to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not perfect but might help.
You can create a [search template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Search_Result_display) and create your user query after/before the main loop like this:

```
$search = get_query_var( 's' );
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array(
  'search' => "*{$search}*",
  'search_columns' => array(
        'user_login',
        'user_nicename',
        'user_email',
        'user_url',
  ),
  'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
              'key' => 'first_name',
              'value' => $search,
              'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
              'key' => 'last_name',
              'value' => $search,
              'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
  )
      ) );
```